# No converter found capable of converting from type to type - entity to DTO

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, mapstruct

I have a issue converting my return entity to a simple DTO in a Springboot project.

I presume a converter is used (no springdata magic) and so are using Map Struct.

The error is:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.nz.bird.dto.BirdTestDTO]
```

My bird class:

```
@Entity
@Data

public class Bird {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name must not be null or empty")
    private String name;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Sex sex;
    // some other fields
```

My my bird test DTO:

```
@Data
public class BirdTestDTO {

private String name;
private String sex;

    public BirdTestDTO(String name, String sex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public BirdTestDTO(){};
```

The repository looks like:

```
@Query("SELECT b.name, b.sex FROM Bird b WHERE b.id = 1")
BirdTestDTO findmyBird();
```

And the Mapper:

```
    @MapperConfig(
    componentModel = "spring",
    builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true)
    )

    @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
    public interface BirdMapper {

        BirdTestDTO birdToBirdTestDTO(Bird bird);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add default (no args) constructor to `BirdTestDTO`

Comment: Why are you posting the Bird->BirdDTO mapper? The conversion error states it tries to map from `AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap`. You'd generally return a domain object from the repo (in your case `Bird`), not a DTO like you declare the method.

Comment: @daniu with the conversion normally on the controller?

Comment: Yes. It's possible you can do it your way if you [let your mapper implement Spring's `Converter` and register it](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions).

Comment: @daniu nearly there returning entity now but getting No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [com.nz.bird.model.Bird]